# Campaigns, surveys, custom fields...?

Tags: profile, civicampaign, civisurvey

Scenario: based on a set of custom fields, we want to send a invite out to individuals for them to join a research study (set up as a group in civi).

I thought the way to go was to create a profile with the custom fields we need updating and then send it out via a campaign/survey. But cannot link the custom profile and the survey.

Do i have to have a campaign in order to set up a survey?
Are the custom fields on the correct entity (currently on entity contact).. should it be on activity instead? and then select the activity 'survey'... going round in circles on this!

Or am i looking in the wrong place using survey for this?  we would not be using any of the functionality on releasing/reserving respondents as they would be filling the data direct themselves.

Using campaigns/survey looks ideal in terms of getting an overview on individuals/engagement index etc

.........
alternative simpler question to the above.. **how do you add custom questions to a survey which the target contact completes** (not a door knocking interviewer)

Comment: if you are using Drupal the webform_civicrm integration is superb for this, using custom fields on a civi Activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at petitions. I have accomplished something similar using a petition. The documentation is here: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/petition/what-is-civipetition/

Hope this helps

Comment: Petitions looks good, much better option than survey.. thanks!